# The data aren't showing in the table in first render. ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Can someone help me. If I render/refresh the page the data are not displaying in the table, if I go to the other page then come back to this page then the data will show up. I want it that every time I render/refresh the page the data will automatically display in the table.

[First Render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LXgC1.png)

[Shown Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HHsWU.png)

This is the page

```html
const headCells = [
  { id: 'action', label: 'ACTION', disableSorting: true },
  { id: 'lastname', label: 'LASTNAME' },
  { id: 'firstname', label: 'FIRSTNAME' },
  { id: 'middlename', label: 'MIDDLENAME' },
  { id: 'email', label: 'EMAIL ADDRESS' },
  { id: 'contactnumber', label: 'CONTACT NO.', disableSorting: true },
  { id: 'usertype', label: 'USER TYPE', disableSorting: true },
  { id: 'address', label: 'ADDRESS' },
  { id: 'username', label: 'USERNAME' },
  { id: 'password', label: 'PASSWORD' },
]

const Grades = ({ resultList, onGetUserList, isLoading, error }) => {

  const classes = useStyles();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [recordForEdit, setEdit] = useState(null)
  const [openEditPopup, setEditOpenPopup] = useState(false);
  const [openAddPopup, setAddOpenPopup] = useState(false);
  const [notify, setNotify] = useState({ isOpen: false, message: '', type: '' })
  const [confirmDialog, setConfirmDialog] = useState({ isOpen: false, title: '', subTitle: '' })
  const [records, setRecords] = useState(resultList)
  const [filterFn, setFilterFn] = useState({ fn: items => { return items; } })
  const [pageSearch, setPageSearch] = useState(false);

  const nofitFunction = (resetForm) => {
    resetForm()
    setAddOpenPopup(false)
    setNotify({
      isOpen: true,
      message: 'Submitted Successfully',
      type: 'success'
    })
    if (error) {
      setNotify({
        isOpen: true,
        message: 'Submit Error',
        type: 'error'
      })
    }
  }

  const toEdit = (detail) => {
    setEdit(detail)
    setEditOpenPopup(true)
  }

  const updateNotif = () => {
    setEditOpenPopup(false)
    setNotify({
      isOpen: true,
      message: 'Updated Successfully',
      type: 'success'
    })
    if (error) {
      setNotify({
        isOpen: true,
        message: 'Updated Error',
        type: 'error'
      })
    }
  }

  const toConfirm = (id, e) => {
    setConfirmDialog({
      ...confirmDialog,
      isOpen: false
    })
    dispatch(deleteUser(id));
    setNotify({
      isOpen: true,
      message: 'Deleted Successfully',
      type: 'success'
    })
    if (error) {
      setNotify({
        isOpen: true,
        message: 'Delete Error',
        type: 'error'
      })
    }
  }

  const handleDocumentTitle = () => {
    document.title = 'GLC Inc. | Grades';
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    handleDocumentTitle();
    onGetUserList();
  }, [onGetUserList]);

  useEffect(() => {
    handleSearchChange();
  }, [pageSearch])

  const {
    TblContainer,
    TblHead,
    TblPagination,
    recordsAfterPagingAndSorting,
    handleSearchChange,
  } = useTable(records, headCells, filterFn);

  const handleSearch = e => {
    let target = e.target;
    target.value === '' ? setPageSearch(false) : setPageSearch(true);
    setFilterFn({
      fn: items => {
        if (target.value === ''){
          return items;
        }
        else {
          return items.filter(x => x.lastname?.toLowerCase().includes(target.value))
      }
    }
    })
  }

  /**
  * show a loading indicator while fetching isn't done yet
  * see @reducer
  */
  if (isLoading) {
    return <ProgressIndicator />;
  }

  /**
   * every time an error occured,
   * always inform the users and give them the chance to
   * @reload
   */
  if (error) {
    return <ErrorHandler message={error} onRetry={onGetUserList} />;
  }

  return (
    <>
      <h3>Grades Management</h3>
      <Paper className={classes.paperheader}>
        <Grid className={classes.header}>
          <Grid>
            <Toolbar>
              <Controls.Input
                placeholder='Search...'
                className={classes.searchInput}
                InputProps={{
                  startAdornment: (<InputAdornment position="start">
                    <Search />
                  </InputAdornment>)
                }}
                onChange={handleSearch}
              />
            </Toolbar>
          </Grid>
          <Grid>
            <Controls.Button
              text="Add New User"
              size="small"
              classStyle={classes.add}
              startIcon={<AddIcon />}
              onClick={() => setAddOpenPopup(true)} />
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
        <TblContainer>
          <TblHead />
          <TableBody>
            { resultList &&
              recordsAfterPagingAndSorting().map((item, index) => {
                const { _id, lastname, firstname, middlename, email, contactnumber, usertype, address, username, password, } =
                  item;
                return (
                  <TableRow key={index}>
                    <TableCell>
                      <div className={classes.action}>
                        <Grid className={classes.buttonstyle}>
                          <Controls.ActionButton
                            color="primary"
                            onClick={() => { toEdit(item) }}>
                            <Tooltip title="Edit" placement="top">
                              <DriveFileRenameOutlineRoundedIcon fontSize="small" />
                            </Tooltip>
                          </Controls.ActionButton>
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid>
                          <Controls.ActionButton
                            color="secondary"
                            onClick={() => {
                              setConfirmDialog({
                                isOpen: true,
                                title: 'Delete Confirmation.',
                                subTitle: "Are you sure to delete this?",
                                onConfirm: () => { toConfirm(_id) }
                              })
                            }}>
                            <Tooltip title="Delete" placement="top">
                              <DeleteIcon fontSize="small" />
                            </Tooltip>
                          </Controls.ActionButton>
                        </Grid>
                      </div>
                    </TableCell>
                    <TableCell>{lastname}</TableCell>
                    <TableCell>{firstname}</TableCell>
                    <TableCell>{middlename}</TableCell>
                    <TableCell>{email}</TableCell>
                    <TableCell>{contactnumber}</TableCell>
                    <TableCell>{usertype}</TableCell>
                    <TableCell>{address}</TableCell>
                    <TableCell>{username}</TableCell>
                    <TableCell>{password}</TableCell>
                  </TableRow>
                )
              })}
          </TableBody>
        </TblContainer>
        <TblPagination />
      </Paper>
      <Popup
        title="Add User"
        openPopup={openAddPopup}
        setOpenPopup={setAddOpenPopup}>
        <GradesForm
          nofitFunction={nofitFunction} />
      </Popup>

      <Popup
        title="Update User"
        openPopup={openEditPopup}
        setOpenPopup={setEditOpenPopup}>
        <UpdateGradesForm
          recordForEdit={recordForEdit}
          updateNotif={updateNotif} />
      </Popup>

      <Notification
        notify={notify}
        setNotify={setNotify} />
      <ConfirmDialog
        confirmDialog={confirmDialog}
        setConfirmDialog={setConfirmDialog} />
    </>
  )
};
```

This is my reusable table component with paging, sorting, and filtering

```html
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { Table, TableHead, TableRow, TableCell, makeStyles, TablePagination, TableSortLabel } from '@material-ui/core'
import {
    WHITE,
    DIRTWHITE
} from 'styles/colors.styles';

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    table: {
        marginTop: '1.5em',
        '& thead th': {
            fontWeight: '600',
            color: WHITE,
            backgroundColor: theme.palette.primary.light,
        },
        '& tbody td': {
            textAlign: 'center',
            fontWeight: '300',
        },
        '& tbody tr': {
            '&:nth-of-type(even)': {
                backgroundColor: DIRTWHITE,
            },
            '&.MuiTableRow-root': {
                borderRadius: '20px',
            },
        },
    },
}))


export default function useTable(records, headCells, filterFn) {

    const classes = useStyles();

    const pages = [5, 10, 25]
    const [page, setPage] = useState(0)
    const [rowsPerPage, setRowsPerPage] = useState(pages[page])
    const [order, setOrder] = useState()
    const [orderBy, setOrderBy] = useState()

    const TblContainer = props => (
        <Table className={classes.table}>
            {props.children}
        </Table>
    )

    const TblHead = props => {

        const handleSortRequest = cellId => {
            const isAsc = orderBy === cellId && order === "asc";
            setOrder(isAsc ? 'desc' : 'asc');
            setOrderBy(cellId)
        }

        return (<TableHead>
            <TableRow>
                {
                    headCells.map(headCell => (
                        <TableCell key={headCell.id} 
                            sortDirection={orderBy === headCell.id ? order : false}
                            align='center'
                            >
                            {headCell.disableSorting ? headCell.label :
                                <TableSortLabel
                                    active={orderBy === headCell.id}
                                    direction={orderBy === headCell.id ? order : 'asc'}
                                    onClick={() => { handleSortRequest(headCell.id) }}>
                                    {headCell.label}
                                </TableSortLabel>
                            }
                        </TableCell>))
                }
            </TableRow>
        </TableHead>)
    }

    const handleSearchChange = () => {
        setPage(0);
    }

    const handleChangePage = (event, newPage) => {
        setPage(newPage);
    }

    const handleChangeRowsPerPage = event => {
        setRowsPerPage(parseInt(event.target.value, 10))
        setPage(0);
    }

    const TblPagination = () => (<TablePagination
        component="div"
        page={page}
        rowsPerPageOptions={pages}
        rowsPerPage={rowsPerPage}
        count={records.length}
        onChangePage={handleChangePage}
        onChangeRowsPerPage={handleChangeRowsPerPage}
    />)

    function stableSort(array, comparator) {
        const stabilizedThis = array.map((el, index) => [el, index]);
        stabilizedThis.sort((a, b) => {
            const order = comparator(a[0], b[0]);
            if (order !== 0) return order;
            return a[1] - b[1];
        });
        return stabilizedThis.map((el) => el[0]);
    }

    function getComparator(order, orderBy) {
        return order === 'desc'
            ? (a, b) => descendingComparator(a, b, orderBy)
            : (a, b) => -descendingComparator(a, b, orderBy);
    }

    function descendingComparator(a, b, orderBy) {
        if (b[orderBy] < a[orderBy]) {
            return -1;
        }
        if (b[orderBy] > a[orderBy]) {
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    const recordsAfterPagingAndSorting = () => {
        return stableSort(filterFn.fn(records), getComparator(order, orderBy))
            .slice(page * rowsPerPage, (page + 1) * rowsPerPage)
    }

    // useEffect(() => {
    //     recordsAfterPagingAndSorting();
    //   }, []);

    return {
        TblContainer,
        TblHead,
        TblPagination,
        recordsAfterPagingAndSorting,
        handleSearchChange
    }
}
```

Comment: Returning components from a hook is going to cause weird stuff because a new component type is going to be returned every render. Instead I think that hook should be a component that uses render props.

Comment: how should i do that sir?